# How to pass down props to decorated form in `redux-form`?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm building a Wizard Form with `redux-form` and encountering an issue where an `onClick` handler is not being passed down as a prop from the container component into the form.

I've searched the docs for the past few hours to no avail...it seems that there may be a way to pass the props into the decorated HOC, but I can't see any such examples.

Here is the relevant code:

`RadioButtons.js` (where the onClick function is called)

```
const RadioButtons = props => {
  const { question, handleClick } = props;
  const radioClassNames = classNames({
    "radio-button": true,
    "radio-button-image-wrapper": question.image,
    "radio-button-text-wrapper": !question.image,
  });
  return (
    <div className="radio-buttons">
      <div className="radio-buttons-wrapper">
        {question.options.map((option, index) => (
          <div className={radioClassNames} key={index} onClick={handleClick}>
            <Field
              component="input"
              type="radio"
              name={`option-${option}`}
              id={`option-${option}`}
            />
            <label className="radio-button-text" htmlFor={option}>
              {option}
            </label>
        )}
          </div>
        )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

RadioButtons.PropTypes = {
  question: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  handleClick: PropTypes.func,
}

export default RadioButtons;
```

When I inspect this component in React DevTools, it doesn't have this prop. Nor is it in the following component...

`Question.js` (this determines what kind of question to render; slider, radio buttons, text/email/tel input, etc.)

```
const Question = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, onBlur, question, handleClick } = props;
  return (
    <div className={`question question-${question.name}`}>
      <form className={props.className} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="question-wrapper">
          <label className={`question-label-${question.name}`}>{question.text}</label>
          { question.image === true && question.type !== "checkbox" && question.type !== "radio" &&
            <img className="question-image" src={`/images/${question.name}.png`} />
          }
          { question.type === "radio" && <RadioButtons question={question} handleClick={handleClick} /> }
          { question.type === "range" && <Slider question={question} /> }
          { question.type !== "checkbox" && question.type !== "radio" && question.type !== "range" &&
            <Field
              component={question.component}
              type={question.type}
              name={question.name}
              placeholder={question.placeholder}
              onBlur={onBlur}
            />
          }
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

Question.PropTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  onBlur: PropTypes.func,
  question: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  handleClick: PropTypes.func,
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'quiz',
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
})(Question);
```

`QuestionContainer.js` (wrapper for `Question.js`; determines whether to render multiple questions on the screen or just one). The `handleClick` prop **finally shows up here!**

```
const QuestionContainer = props => {
  const { question, handleClick } = props;

  const questionClassNames = classNames({
    'question-wrapper': true,
    'question-single': props.question !== 'combined',
    'question-multiple': props.question === 'combined',
  });

  const renderQuestions = question => {
    if (question.component === 'combined') {
      return (
       <div className="multi-question-container">
         <label className="multi-question-label">{question.text}</label>
         <div className="multi-question-wrapper">
           {question.subQuestions.map((subQuestion, index) => {
             const newName = `${question.name}-${subQuestion.name}`;
             const newSubQuestion = Object.assign({}, subQuestion, { name: newName })
             return (
               <Question
                 question={newSubQuestion}
                 key={index}
                 className={questionClassNames}
                 handleClick={handleClick}
               />
             )
           })}
         </div>
       </div>
      )} else {
       return (
         <Question
           question={question}
           className={questionClassNames}
         />
       )
     }
  }

  return (
    <div className="question-container">
      {renderQuestions(question)}
    </div>
  )
}

QuestionContainer.PropTypes = {
  question: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  handleClick: PropTypes.func,
}

export default QuestionContainer;
```

But then...the `handleClick` prop **doesn't show up** in the `Quiz` component, where I actually need to use it to call `nextScreen()`:

```
class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      screen: 0
    }
  }

  nextScreen = () => {
    console.log("nextScreen");
    if (this.state.screen < data.questions.length) {
      this.setState({screen: this.state.screen + 1});
    } else {
      this.props.calculateResult(this.props.form.quiz.values);
      this.props.history.push('/congratulations');
    }
  }

  lastScreen = () => {
    if (this.state.screen > 1) {
      this.setState({screen: this.state.screen - 1});
    } else {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }

  render() {

    const currentQuestion = Object.assign({}, data.questions[this.state.screen]);

    let arrowSource = `/images/arrow-button-${arrowColor}.png`;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="quiz-wrapper">
          <ArrowButton src={arrowSource} route="back" handleClick={this.lastScreen} />
          <div className="quiz-wrapper-inner">
            <QuestionContainer question={currentQuestion} handleClick={this.nextScreen} />
          </div>
          <ArrowButton src={arrowSource} route="forward" handleClick={this.nextScreen} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    form: state.form,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    calculateResult: answers => dispatch(calculateResult(answers)),
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Quiz);
```

The `handleClick` prop on the `ArrowButton` component works fine, calling `nextScreen()`/`lastScreen()` without a hitch. It's only in the `QuestionContainer` that it isn't getting passed down.

Comment: As I see you are passing it down in one instance and not in the other, So if question.component is not combined its not passed and thats when it won't be available in th eQuestion component , See `<Question
           question={question}
           className={questionClassNames}
         />`

Comment: Of course! Can't believe I didn't see this. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of `Questions` Component in the `QuestionsContainer` component. When the `question.component === 'combined'` condition is met, you are passing the `handleClick` prop but **not otherwise** and hence it is not available in your `Questions` component.

You need to pass handleClick as a prop in the else condition as well

```
const renderQuestions = question => {
    if (question.component === 'combined') {
      return (
       <div className="multi-question-container">
         <label className="multi-question-label">{question.text}</label>
         <div className="multi-question-wrapper">
           {question.subQuestions.map((subQuestion, index) => {
             const newName = `${question.name}-${subQuestion.name}`;
             const newSubQuestion = Object.assign({}, subQuestion, { name: newName })
             return (
               <Question
                 question={newSubQuestion}
                 key={index}
                 className={questionClassNames}
                 handleClick={handleClick}
               />
             )
           })}
         </div>
       </div>
      )} else {
       return (
         <Question
           question={question}
           className={questionClassNames}
           handleClick={handleClick}
         />
       )
     }
  }
```